# Powershell "private" scope seems not useful at all

Tags: powershell, scope, private

I've got the script below, from internet:

```
$private:a = 1
Function test  {
    "variable a contains $a"
    $a = 2
    "variable a contains $a"
}
test
```

It prints 2. No problem. If I delete "private", like below:

```
$a = 1
Function test  {
    "variable a contains $a"
    $a = 2
    "variable a contains $a"
}
```

Still it prints "2". Seems no difference. Could you provide an quick sample of how "private" scope affects the result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Private scope can be useful when writing a function that invokes a user-supplied callback. Consider this simple example:

```
filter Where-Name {
    param(
        [ScriptBlock]$Condition
    )
    $FirstName, $LastName = $_ -split ' '
    if(&$Condition $FirstName $LastName) {
        $_
    }
}
```

Then, if someone calls it like this:

```
$FirstName = 'First2'
'First1 Last1', 'First2 Last2', 'First3 Last3' |
  Where-Name {param($a, $b) $a -eq $FirstName}
```

they'll expect to see only the `First2 Last2` row, but actually this will print all three rows.
This is because of a collision on the `$FirstName` variable.
To prevent such collisions, you can declare variables in `Where-Name` as private:

```
filter Where-Name {
    param(
        [ScriptBlock]$private:Condition
    )
    $private:FirstName, $private:LastName = $_ -split ' '
    if(&$Condition $FirstName $LastName) {
        $_
    }
}
```

Now `$FirstName` in `Where-Name` does not hide `$FirstName` in the outer scope when referenced from the `$Condition` script block.

Comment: Helpful, but there's a problem when applying `private:` to _parameters_; consider: `function foo([ScriptBlock] $private:sb) { & $private:sb }; $sb = 'hi'`; This works fine when invoked _positionally_: `foo { $sb } # -> 'hi'`; but when you try to use the _parameter name_, you can't: `foo -sb { $sb }` FAILS, because PS now thinks the parameter name is `-private:sb`, which, however cannot be used, because PS then interprets the part after `:` - `sb` - as the parameter _value_: `foo -private:sb { $sb }` FAILS too. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @mklement0 If you use v2+, then you better to use modules. IMHO, them do that better then private scope. And you can use splatting to supply such weird parameter name: `$p = @{ 'private:sb' = { $sb } }; foo @p`.

Comment: Great idea to use modules, thanks for the tip; in v3+, this can even be done _dynamically_: `$null = New-Module { function foo([ScriptBlock] $sb) { & $sb } }; $sb = 'hi'; foo { $sb }`. Btw, it seems that if you do want to use a `$private:` _parameter_ after all, you must keep using `$private:` when _referencing_ that parameter later (_variables_ don't seem to have that requirement); i.e.: `& $private:Condition ...`.

Comment: @mklement0 It work for me as it is: with out adding `private:` when I reference `$Condition` inside function body.

Comment: It works for your specific example, but that's because `$Condition` doesn't exist in the outer scope. Contrast these examples: `function foo([ScriptBlock] $private:sb) { & $private:sb }; $sb = 'hi'; foo { $sb }` - works (outputs `'hi'`); if I remove the 2nd `$private:`, it doesn't work (`$sb` then refers to the value in the _outer_ scope rather than the variable): `function foo([ScriptBlock] $private:sb) { & $sb }; $sb = 'hi'; foo { $sb }` (PS version 5.0.10586.63)

Comment: @mklement0 For me it look like a bug in v5 (guessing it actually since v3, IMHO, it is DLR optimization bug). In v2 it print `hi` and if I write it like this: `function foo([ScriptBlock] $private:sb) { & $sb; if($false){$private:sb} }; $sb = 'hi'; foo { $sb }` — it print `hi` in v5.

Comment: @mklement0 `$a=1; &{$a;$a+=2;$a;(gv a).GetType().FullName}; '-'; &{$a;$a+=2;$a;(gv a).GetType().FullName;if($false){rv}}; '-'; &{$a;$a+=2;$a;(gv a).GetType().FullName;rv a;$a}; '-'; sal x rv; &{$a;$a+=2;$a;(gv a).GetType().FullName;x a;$a}`

Comment: Astounding stuff, thanks for digging deeper; as your last command shows, PS clearly *tries* to anticipate DLR optimization troubles, but there are bugs  (which aren't in PSv2) - have you notified the PS team? As for the answer: can I suggest removing the `$private` from the `Condition` parameter to avoid confusion, and adding the tip to use modules instead directly to the answer?

Comment: @mklement0 IIRC, I post about this on Microsoft Connect, not sure if it got migrated to UserVoice. Actually, even putting parameters into `param` block fix this: `function foo { param([ScriptBlock] $private:sb) & $sb }; $sb = 'hi'; foo { $sb }`. Although, if you think that removing `$private` will clarify the answer, feel free to do that.

Answer (score 18):

<sup>Note:
* This answer **explains why** the OP's code behaves the way it does (and that it behaves as designed); additionally, it provides some **general information about variable scopes** in PowerShell.
* For an **important real-world use** of scope `private`, see  [PetSerAl's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36352633/45375).</sup>

Your first snippet prints:

```
variable a contains
variable a contains 2
```

Your second snippet prints:

```
variable a contains 1
variable a contains 2
```

In the first snippet, using scope `private` causes the parent (script) scope's `a` variable to be *hidden* from the child (function) scope, as designed, so the first output line shows that `$a` has *no* value
(an undefined variable has value `$null`, which evaluates to the empty string in a string context).

In the second snippet, by contrast, without the `private` scope modifier, variable `a` from the parent scope is *visible* to the child scope.

In PowerShell, functions execute in *child* scopes by default.

Therefore, in *both* snippets above, *assigning* to variable `$a` inside the function implicitly creates a *local* `$a` variable there, whose scope is limited to the enclosing function.

In other words:

- *Assigning* to `$a` *in the function* creates a *function-local* variable named `$a`, which then *shadows* (hides) the *script-level* `$a` variable (if it wasn't already hidden by having been declared as `$private:a`) - though note that *local* in PowerShell means that *child* scopes *do* see its value; see next section.
- On leaving the function, `$a` again has its original, script-level value.

---

#### General information about *variable scopes* in PowerShell

Note:

- The discussion focuses on *variables*, but in principle it applies to *all* scoped entities, namely also to *functions*, *aliases*, PowerShell *drives*, and modules. However, only *variables* allow *modification* of instances in ancestral scopes.
- The discussion is limited to code that runs *in a given session's main runspace* (its main thread) and therefore **does *not* apply to *out-of-runspace* contexts**, namely:

  - *Remote* calls (such as via `Invoke-Command -ComputerName`), *background jobs* (started with `Start-Job`), *thread jobs* (`Start-ThreadJob`, PSv6+) and thread-based parallel processing (`ForEach-Object -Parallel`, PSv7+).
  - Such contexts *do not share state* with the main runspace and only the *values* of variables can be passed to them, via the **`$using:` scope**; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60012780/45375) for details.
- As most shells do, **PowerShell uses *dynamic* rather than *lexical* scoping**.

  - That is, rather than variables being visible only to the enclosing *lexical construct*, such as a function definition, variable visibility depends on the *runtime call stack*. To give a simplified example: if function A defines a variable and then calls function B, B sees that variable by default. In other words: **what variables a given function or script sees depends on *who called it***.
- *Global* variables (e.g., `$global:foo`) are *session*-global in PowerShell, and therefore best avoided, unless they are truly needed throughout an entire session.
- See also: The conceptual [about_Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes) help topic.

**Overview**:

- **Unless a variable is explicitly hidden with scope `private`, descendant scopes *see* that variable** and *read* its value using the variable name *without a scope qualifier* (e.g., `$a`) or the need for `Get-Variable -Scope`.

  - E.g., `$foo = 'bar'; function Get-Foo { $foo }; Get-Foo` outputs `'bar'`, because the child scope in which the function runs sees the caller's `$foo` variable..
  - Note that while descendant scopes do not *see* the values of variables created *with `$private:`* by default, they can still refer to them with *relative* cross-scope access, using `Get-Variable -Scope` or `Set-Variable -Scope`.
    *Non-relative* scope modifiers (`$script`, `$global`, `$local`) generally do *not* work - *except* if the reference happens in the same scope in which the private variable was created and the scope modifier happens to effectively target that same scope, which is always true for `$local:privateVarName`, for instance.
- ***Assigning* to an unqualified variable, however, implicitly creates a *new* variable in the *current* (`local`) scope**, which can *shadow* a variable of the same name in an ancestral scope.

  - That is, `$a = 2` is implicitly the same as `$local:a = 2`.
  - E.g., `$foo = 'bar'; function Get-Foo { $foo = 'bar2'; $foo }; Get-Foo; $foo` outputs `bar2` and `bar`, because the unqualified assignment `$foo = 'bar2'` created a *local* `$foo` variable inside the function (which then *shadows* the caller's `$foo` inside the function), leaving the caller's `$foo` untouched.
- **To explicitly get / modify a variable in an ancestral scope, use `Get-Variable / Set-Variable -Scope <n> <name>`**, where `<n>` represents the scope level, with `0` representing the current scope, `1` the parent scope, and so on.
  Note that `Get-Variable` returns a `[System.Management.Automation.PSVariable]` instance by default, so in order to get only the *value*, access its `.Value` property, or use the `-ValueOnly` switch, which only returns the value to begin with.

  - In *functions* and *trap handlers*, *before* creating a local copy of a variable, you can alternatively *modify a variable in the most immediate ancestral scope where it is defined* as follows:

    - `([ref] $var).Value = ...`
    - (If and once a local variable by the same name is created, the above will modify only the *local* variable, however.)
  - **Variables in the *script* scope and the *global* scope** can also be accessed - and modified - by using the **`$script:` and `$global:` scope modifiers**; e.g., `$script:a` and `$global:a`.
    Note that `$script:` refers to the (immediately) *enclosing script file's* top-level scope.
- ***[Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules)*** each have their **own *scope domain* (aka *session state*)**, which is **linked only to the *global* scope.** That is, **modules see outside variables only from the *global* scope, not from a caller in any other scope**, such as from a *script* (the exception is if the caller is *from the same module*); this can cause unexpected behavior with [preference variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables), as discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4568).

  - In short:

    - All *non-module* code runs in a (the same) scope domain.
    - Each module has its own scope domain.
    - The only scope shared by all scope domains is the one and only *global* one, which functions as the *root scope* for all scope domains.
- **Declaring a variable with `Set-Variable -Option AllScope` allows it to be read *and modified* in *any descendant* scope *without needing to qualify the name***; to put it differently: only a *single* variable by that name exists then, which *any scope can directly read and write using the unqualified variable name*.

  - Without a separate `-Scope` parameter, `-Option AllScope` is applied to the variable in the *current* scope (e.g., the script scope at the script's top level, a function's local scope inside a function). Thus, to safely create a *script*-global variable that you can access unqualified for reading *and* writing, use `Set-Variable -Scope Script -Option AllScope`.
  - **`-Scope Global` is distinct from `-Option AllScope`**: while `-Scope Global` creates a globally accessible variable, reading it *may*, and modifying it *does*, require the `$global:` scope modifier, and, without `-Option AllScope`, global variables can be *shadowed* by variables of the same name in descendant scopes. Also note that **a global variable is *session*-global**, so it persists even after the script that defined it has terminated.
  - By **combining `-Scope Global` with `-Option AllScope` you effectively create a *session*-global singleton variable** that can be read and written from any scope without qualifier; as stated, however, such a variable lives on even after your script exits.

Answer (score 0):

Good software design means minimized coupling (among other things). Within Powershell, that includes using private ON EVERY VARIABLE YOU CAN. If you want to make a value available in some subsequently called module, pass that information EXPLICITLY. There should be a very good EXCEPTION reason for not doing this, because each time you rely on implicit knowledge (e.g. the kind that happens in Powershell when you don't use private variables), you increase the chance something will go unexpectedly wrong later (maybe months later when the software has a lot more code in it).

Comment: Good recommendation, but it means always having to be explicit on creation (`$private:var = ...`  instead of `$var = ...`). Also, given that the question is about how the private scope works, not whether or not it's a good idea to use it, I suggest framing your answer accordingly.