# Difference between Clear-Variable and setting variable to NULL

Tags: powershell, variables, scopes

I often use variables which are declared in the script scope to avoid problems with functions and their scopes. I am declaring these variables like this:

```
New-Variable -Name test -Option AllScope -Value $null
```

... or sometimes I switch existing variables like this to use them comprehensively:

```
$script:test = $test
```

When I want to clear them I either use this:

```
Clear-Variable test -Scope Script
```

... or I simply use this:

```
$test = $null
```

Is there a difference? What should I prefer and why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the get-Help:

> The Clear-Variable cmdlet deletes the data stored in a variable, but it does not delete the variable. As a result,
>       the value of the variable is NULL (empty). If the variable has a specified data or object type, Clear-Variable
>       preserves the type of the object stored in the variable.

So `Clear-Variable` and `$var=$null` are nearly equivalents (with the exception of the typing which is retained). An exact equivalent would be to do `$var=[mytype]$null`.

You can test it yourself:

```
$p = "rrrr"
Test-Path variable:/p     # => $true
$p = $null
Get-Member -InputObject $p     # => error
$p = [string]$null
Get-Member -InputObject $p   # => it is a string
```

And to answer what may be the next question: how to completely remove a variable (since an absent variable is different from a null-valued variable)? Simply do

```
rm variable:/p
Test-Path variable:/p => $false
```

Comment: ++, but for symmetry and the ability to specify a target scope you should mention [`Remove-Variable`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849935.aspx).

Comment: Both `Clear-Variable` and assigning `$null` preserve the type of a type-bound variable (a variable defined with "cast notation"; e.g., `[int] $i = 1`).

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Assigning to `$null` also preserves type information for strongly-typed variables; it might appear different merely because of scope. See [mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568027/difference-between-clear-variable-and-setting-variable-to-null/#37574305).

Comment: How did this get chosen as the accepted answer? It did not even give *any* examples for `Clear-Variable`.

Answer (score 6):

To complement [Marcanpilami's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37568410/45375):

<sup>Note: In order to *remove* (undefine) a variable altogether, use [`Remove-Variable <name> [-Scope <scope>]`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849935.aspx).</sup>

*Unless* `$test` is defined with `Set-Variable -Option AllScope`,

- `Clear-Variable test -Scope Script`

and

- `$test = $null`

are **NOT generally equivalent**.

(*With* `Set-Variable -Option AllScope` they are, but then the `-Scope` argument becomes irrelevant, because then only *one* instance of the variable exists (conceptually), across all scopes.)

`$test = $null` - *unless executed in the same scope* as when variable `test` was originally created - will implicitly *create* a `test` variable in the *current* scope (and assign `$null` to it), and leave the *original* variable untouched.  <sup>For more on variable scoping in PS, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347515/45375)</sup>

Note that **variable-assignment syntax offers scoping too**, via a *scope prefix*, but it is limited to `global`, `script`, and `local` (the default): `$global:test = $null`, `$script:test = $null`, `$local:test = $null`

<sup>There's also the `private` scope: a variation of `local` that prevents *descendant scopes* from seeing a variable - again, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347515/45375).</sup>

**If you've ensured that you *are* targeting the *same scope*, the two forms above are functionally equivalent: they assign `$null` to the target variable.<sup>[1]</sup>**

However, using **`Clear-Variable` allows you to do two things that `$<scope>:testing = ...` doesn't**:

- the **`-Scope` parameter** also accepts a *numeric* value that indicates the **scope *relative* to the current scope**: `0` is the current scope, `1` is the parent scope, and so on.
- you can **target *multiple* variables** (either as an *array* of names or using *wildcards*)

---

[1] **Pitfall**:

Note that **if the target variable is *type-constrained*** (was assigned with "cast notation"; e.g., `[int] $i = 1`), the type is *retained*  - whether using `$testing = $null` or `Clear-Variable` - and an *implicit type conversion* may occur, which can have **unexpected results or fail** altogether:

```bash
[int] $i = 1 # type-constrain $i as an integer
Clear-Variable i # equivalent of $i = $null
$i # !! $i is now 0 (!), because [int] $null yields 0

[datetime] $d = 1 # type-constrain $d as DateTime
Clear-Variable d # !! FAILS, because `$d = $null` fails, given that 
                 # !! $null cannot be converted to [datetime]
```