# Is it ok to string variables together to clear them?

Tags: powershell, variable-assignment

So, it is possible to clear a variable with the [`Clear-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/clear-variable?view=powershell-6) cmdlet which is the same as giving it the value `$null`.

One can also remove a variable with the [`Remove-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/remove-variable?view=powershell-6) cmdlet or the [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-6) cmdlet for environmental variables.

**My question is, is stringing variables together like this...**

```
$Env:var1 = $var2 = $var3 = $null
```

**... a legitimate way of clearing variables or even assigning values?**

I know that `$var1` is independent from `$var2` if you assign values like this: `$var1 = $var2 = 1`, but when the value is an object created with the [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object?view=powershell-6) cmdlet, both variables point to the same object:

```
$var1 = $var2 = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
$var1.Start()
Start-Sleep 1
$var2.Stop()
Start-Sleep 1
$var1.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
```

Is this solely down the value being a `Microsoft .NET Framework` or `COM object`?

Comment: `$var2 = $var1 = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch;;$var1 -eq $var2` returns `true` while `$var2 = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch; $var1 = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch;$var1 -eq $var2` returns `false`. Don't ask me why…

Comment: Read [PowerShell Reference Types And Value Types](https://johnfabry.azurewebsites.net/2015/06/26/powershell-reference-types-and-value-types/) and universal [Difference between a Value Type and a Reference Type](http://net-informations.com/faq/general/valuetype-referencetype.htm).

Comment: @JosefZ Based on what I understand from the articles you linked (thanks!), using the `New-Object` cmdlet creates a reference type variable.

Comment: I don't think so; try e.g.: `$a = $b = New-Object string -ArgumentList "abc";$b='ccc'; $a,$b`

Comment: @JosefZ: Good pointers, and true that `New-Object` is equally capable of creating value types. Your specific example needs explaining, though: as an _exception_, `[string]` (.NET strings) _act like_ value types, but are _technically_ reference types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... a legitimate way of clearing variables

Yes, something like **`$var1 = $var2 = $null`** (to use just *2* variables as an example) is a **legitimate way of clearing variables' values, PROVIDED THAT the target variable(s) are actually *defined* in the *local* (current) scope.**

If they are merely visible from a *parent* (ancestral) scope), you'll inadvertently create *local* variables of the same name whose value is `$null` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55403663/45375).

The same applies to **`Clear-Variable var1, var2`** in principle, except that it will emit an *error* if no *local* variable(s) `$var1` and `$var2` are defined; additionally, `Clear-Variable` allows targeting a different scope explicitly with `-Scope`.

<sup>With limitations, you can also target other scopes with variable assignments, using scope specifiers such as `$script:var` - see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37574305/45375).</sup>

**`Remove-Variable`** acts similarly to `Clear-Variable` and also supports `-Scope`,  but truly *removes* (undefines) variables from the implied or targeted scope.

Note that accessing a removed / non-existent variable *by default* is effectively the same as accessing an existing variable whose value is `$null`.
  However,  with `Set-StrictMode -Version 1` or higher in effect, accessing a non-existent variable fails by design.

**`$var1 = $var2 = $null` has the following advantages over `Clear-Variable var1, var2`**:

- It is more concise and also faster (no cmdlet call needed).
- It can be used to implicitly *create* variables with a `$null` value, or, to put it differently, the statement doesn't fail if one of the variables doesn't exist.
- It can also be used with *environment variables* (e.g., `$env:FOO`), though note that assigning `$null` (or `''`, the empty string) to environment variables actually *removes* them (`$env:FOO = $null` is equivalent to `Remove-Item Env:FOO`).

**Caveat**:

**Assigning `$null` or calling `Clear-Variable` doesn't necessarily result in the variable containing `$null`**:

**Variables may be *type-constrained*,** in which case they only permit storing values of the type locked in at creation (initialization) time:

```
[int] $i = 1  # Create a type-constrained variable that can only store [int] values.
```

When you assign `$null` to a type-constrained variable, PowerShell attempts to *convert* `$null` to the locked-in type, which can have two outcomes:

- The conversion succeeds, in which case the *converted* value of the locked-in type is the new value; for instance, in the case of `[int]`, that value is `0`, because `[int] $null` is `0`.

  ```
  [int] $i = 1; $i = $null; $i # -> 0, not $null
  ```
- The conversion may *fail*, resulting in an error; in the case of `[datetime]`, the conversion fails, because `[datetime] $null` fails.

  ```
  # !! ERROR: Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime"
  [datetime] $dt = Get-Date; $dt = $null
  ```

---

**As for `New-Object` and assigning a *non-null* value to multiple variables:**

As stated in the comments, the resulting behavior comes down to whether a [*value-type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) instance or a [*reference-type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) instance is being assigned<sup>[1]</sup>:

- With *value-type* instances, each variable gets its own *independent copy* of the value.

  ```
  # A value-type instance such as an [int] instance assigns
  # *independent copies* of itself to the target variable(s):
  $var1 = $var2 = 42; $var2 = 43; $var1, $var2 # -> 42, 43
  ```
- With *reference-type* instances, all variables truly reference *the very same object*.

  ```
  # A reference-type instance such as a [hashtable] instance assigns
  # a *reference to itself* to the target variable(s), which therefore
  # all reference the same object.
  $var1 = $var2 = @{one=1}; $var2.one = 2; $var1.one, $var2.one # -> 2, 2
  ```

Note that **`[string]` instances are an exception**: `[string]` is technically a *reference* type, but exhibits *value*-type semantics, so as to provide more intuitive string handling - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/636945/45375).

[`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object) is capable of instantiating either type: if you give it the name of a value type, you'll get a value-type instance; given the name of a reference type, you'll get a reference-type instance.

<sup>However, given that the built-in value types can be instantiated with literals (e.g., `1`) or simple casts (`[int]`), `New-Object` is more typically used to instantiate reference types.</sup>

---

<sup>[1] Given a type or instance, you can inspect the type's `.IsValueType` property to determine if it is a value type or not; e.g., because `[int]` (`System.Int32`) is a value type `[int].IsValueType` and `(1).GetType().IsValueType` yield `$true`, whereas `[System.IO.FileInfo].IsValueType` is `$false`, because the latter is a reference type.</sup>