# How do I share variables among scripts in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, variables, scripting

I have difficulty trying to find an answer that solves this issue online.

I have a script which runs all my other scripts in a particular order.

```
$x=0;
$z=0;
cd *file path* ;
.\filename1.ps1 ; write-host "$x text $z text";
.\filename2.ps1 ; write-host "$x text $z text";
```

In each of these scripts I have options that will add 1 to either variable $x or variable $z

```
$a=Read-Host
if ($a -eq "Option One") {$x = $x+1}
elseif ($a -eq "Option Two") {$z = $z+1}
else {Write-Host "Not a valid option" ; .\filenameX.ps1}
```

The issue is that the script that runs all these scripts won't recognise the change in variable. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naïve answer is to "dot-source" these scripts, i.e. to invoke them with operator `.`

Using `.`  executes the scripts in the *caller's* variable scope, so that top-level modifications of `$x` an `$z` will be visible even after `.\filename1.ps1` and `.\filename2.ps1` have completed.

```
# Note the `. ` preceding the file path - the space after "." is mandatory
. .\filename1.ps1 ; "$x text $z text"
. .\filename2.ps1 ; "$x text $z text"
```

Note, however, that *all* top-level variables created or modified in `.` -invoked scripts will be visible to the caller.

For more on variable scopes in PowerShell, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347515/45375).

---

Better encapsulated options are to either (a) *output* modified values or, less commonly, (b) use of `[ref]` parameters to pass *by-reference variables* to scripts - whose parameters must be declared and assigned to accordingly.

Comment: I believe I figured it out. Is this what you meant? Shared script: `return [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = 'aName'; Ip = 'anIP'; Status = 'aStatus' }`. Other scripts: `$a = .\Common.ps1; $a.Name; $a.Ip; $a.Status`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with respect to encapsulation option (a), @GeorgesZ.

Answer (score 0):

If you define you x (and z) variable with a global scope outside your scripts like this:
`$global:x=0`.
You can increment it inside your scripts like this:
`$global:x = $global:x + 1`