# How to keep a changed function in another function apart from the initial function with PowerShell

Tags: function, powershell

I have a script which loads a function from an external source, I want to keep the function (ConvertDecToHex) loaded after executing the load function (LoadFunction).

Below is an example of extremely simplified code:

```
function LoadFunction ()
{
    $Command = 'function ConvertDecToHex ([int]$value){return "{0:x}" -f $value}'
    Invoke-Expression -Command ($Command)

    ConvertDecToHex 12 #works here
}

LoadFunction
ConvertDecToHex 12 #doesn't work here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JosefZ's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68017543/45375) is probably the best approach.

While it is true that **`.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-)** runs *everything* directly in the caller's scope, including thereby making potentially *auxiliary variables* appear, there is is no need to use aux. variables in your case (and you can generally hide definitions you don't want the caller to see by running inside a *child* scope, via `& { ... }`)):

```
function LoadFunction ()
{
  # Just define the function directly.
  # When the enclosing LoadFunction function is dot-sourced
  # ConvertDecToHex is defined in the caller's scope.
  function ConvertDecToHex ([int]$value){return "{0:x}" -f $value}
}

# Important: Dot-source (.) the LoadFunction call
. LoadFunction

# Now this should work.
ConvertDecToHex 12
```

Note:

- The to-be-exported function is simply defined directly and normally inside the `LoadFunction` body - no need for `Invoke-Expression` (`iex`), which  [should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375)
- To comply with PowerShell's naming conventions, it's better to name your functions `Import-Function` and `ConvertTo-Hex`.

---

**If you want to *avoid dot-sourcing*, you can use `Import-Module`:**

If you place the functions to import in a **separate `*.ps1` file**, you can **use [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module)** to achieve the same effect - but **note that *in effect* that is nothing more than a - more descriptive - *syntax alternative* to dot-sourcing such a file - unless you use a stand-alone `.psm1` *module* file**; see below.

E.g, place the function definition(s) in a file named `functions.ps1`:

```sh
function ConvertDecToHex([int]$value) { return "{0:x}" -f $value }
```

Then call `Import-Module` to import them, i.e. to make the function(s) available in the caller's scope:

```sh
# Note: The "./" (or ".\") prefix is required in order to import
#       from the current dir.
Import-Module ./functions.ps1
```

Note:

- `Import-Module`, as the name suggests, is designed to import [*modules*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules), but it can also be used with regular script files (`.ps1`).
- Modules, even though they're typically and more robustly implemented as *directories* with a prescribed structure of related files, can also be implemented as *stand-alone* files, namely with **filename extension `.psm1`** (note the `m`).

  - Therefore, you could alternatively save your function in file `functions.psm1` rather than `functions.ps1`, for instance, but note that resulting behavior differs:
  - **Modules create their own *scope domain*** (a.k.a session (sub)state) that parallels the scopes in which *non-module* code runs; the only ancestral scope they share is the *global* scope, whereas the definitions from a non-global non-module scope - such as inside a regular `.ps1` script - is *not* seen by functions imported from modules.

    - This behavior **can have unexpected side effects with respect to *preference variables*** - see [GitHub issue #4568](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4568).
  - The upshot is:

    - If you use `Import-Module ./functions.ps1` (regular script file), the imported functions *will* see the caller's definitions (functions, variables, ...). For instance, thanks to PowerShell's [dynamic scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52614225/45375), a variable `$foo` defined in the caller's scope would be visible in the body of your `ConvertDecToHex` function.
    - If you use `Import-Module ./functions.psm1` (stand-alone module file), they will *not*.
      Conversely, the caller will not see *variables* defined in the `.psm1` file, unless they're explicit exported with [`Export-ModuleMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember).
      You may prefer this behavior, because it hides auxiliary variables by default, and because `Export-ModuleMember` also gives you control over what functions and aliases should be exported, so you can also hide auxiliary *functions*.

Comment: The proposal of the Import-Module and psm1 is exactly what I needed, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Apply [Dot sourcing operator `.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#dot-sourcing-operator-)

> Runs a script in the current scope so that any functions, aliases, and
> variables that the script creates are added to the current scope,
> overriding existing ones. Parameters declared by the script become
> variables.

Fixed script:

```
function LoadFunction ()
{
    $Command = 'function ConvertDecToHex ([int]$value){return "{0:x}" -f $value}'
    Invoke-Expression -Command ($Command)

    ConvertDecToHex 12 #works here
}

. LoadFunction     # dot source
ConvertDecToHex 12
```

**Output**: `D:\PShell\SO\68016859.ps1`

> ```
> c
> c
> ```

Dot source the script as well if you want to use the `ConvertDecToHex` outside the script:

```
PS D:\PShell> . D:\PShell\SO\68016859.ps1
c
c
PS D:\PShell> ConvertDecToHex 12
c
PS D:\PShell>
```

Comment: It's not a bad idea but I want to do it in the function if possible.
The point source has a downside that everything is in current scope and I don't want it