# PowerShell - Call a function created in another function

Tags: windows, function, powershell, scope

When I run this:

```
function Setup-One{

    function First-Function{
    Write-Host "First function!"
    }

    function Second-Function{
    Write-Host "Second function!"
    }
}
Setup-One
```

And than I call `First-Function` or `Second-Function`, PS says that they don't exist. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68016859/45375

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Function definitions are *scoped*, meaning that they stop existing when you leave the scope in which they were defined.

Use the `.` dot-source operator when invoking `Setup`, thereby persisting the nested functions in the calling scope:

```
function Setup-One{

    function First-Function{
    Write-Host "First function!"
    }

    function Second-Function{
    Write-Host "Second function!"
    }
}
. Setup-One

# Now you can resolve First-Function/Second-Function
First-Function
Second-Function
```

See the [`about_Scopes` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes) for moreinformation on scoping in PowerShell

Comment: Alternatively, `function global:First-Function` inside `Setup-One` overrides the scope on a per-declaration basis (what's more convenient varies by how much you intend to expose).

Comment: @JeroenMostert feel free to add an answer, but I'm not going to suggest that :-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you very much bro

Comment: This right here - Thanks you @MathiasR.Jessen -- This answer is a life saver!