# How can I rename files by prepending a sequence number to the original file names?

Tags: powershell, file-rename, sequential-number

guys does anyone know how can i do this? I am trying to list some files in a numerical order by adding 1, 2, 3 and so on to the beginning of the file names while also keeping the files' original names.

Here are the codes i tried

```
$nr = 1

Dir -path C:\x\y\deneme | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName (‘{0} $_.Name.txt’ -f $nr++ )}

dir | select name
```

This code just orders the files like 1, 2, 3... Without keeping the original names.

---

```
$n = 1
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace $_.Name ,'{0} $_.Name' -f $n++}
```

This one did not work like i thought.

Comment: So you don't want to actually rename them?

Comment: "This one did not work like i thought." - can you tell us how it _did_ work? :-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Actually it did nothing at all. It kept the files' names the same.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I just want to rename them with the addition of numbers but i want to keep the names of the files aside from that.

Comment: Ok, you actually want to copy the files...

Comment: @Burak, So you do want to **rename** them in numerical order (*while keeping the original name*) and not just **list** them in numerical order?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Yes exactly. The first code puts them in the numerical order but it also changes the names such as "1 $_.Name.txt", "2 $_.Name.txt"... resulting in a one common name for all the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, which renames all `.txt` files in the current dir. by prepending a sequence number to them:

```
$n = 1
Get-ChildItem *.txt | 
  Rename-Item -WhatIf -NewName { '{0} {1}' -f ([ref] $n).Value++, $_.Name }
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

The `([ref] $n).Value++` trick makes up for the fact that [delay-bind script blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) run in a *child* scope of the caller, where the caller's variables are *seen*, but applying `++` (or assigning a value) creates a *transient, local copy* of the variable (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52614225/45375) for an overview of PowerShell's scoping rules).
`[ref] $n` in effect returns a reference to the caller's variable object, whose `.Value` property can then be updated.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `'{0} $_.Name.txt'`, as a *single*-quoted string, is interpreted *verbatim* by PowerShell; you cannot embed variable references in such strings; for that you need *double*-quoting (`"..."`, and you'd also need `$(...)` in order to embed an *expression* such as `$_.Name`) - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375) for an overview of PowerShell's string literals.

Comment: Well, I was trying to find a way of incrementing `$n` inside the `Rename-Item` ScriptBlock... I guess I learn something new today, again and again lol you're awesome man!

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon :) The behavior - and the solution - are definitely obscure; if you're interested in a related conceptual discussion, see [GitHub issue #](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7157).

Comment: @AbrahamZinala :) perhaps the GitHub link in my previous comment helps. There's also a less obscure, but more verbose alternative to `([ref] $n).Value++`, and that is `(Get-Variable n -Scope 1).Value++` - and if you can assume that the caller is a script's (top-level) scope, `$script:n++`

Comment: I meant to say, inside the `-Destination {...}` scriptblock of `Copy-Item` which, trying it out works perfect too, except for files are copied to the current dir instead of the dir where `gci` is pointing too (hope it makes sense) hence why I used that `Join-Path` to copy files to where the actual files are.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, yes, only with `Rename-Item`'s `-NewName` parameter, whose argument must only ever be a file _name_, is the argument guaranteed to refer to the same directory as the input path.

Answer (score 1):

So yeah, I agree with [@Abraham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala), I don't see a scenario where you can **rename** the files but also **retain** the original files without copying them :)

This should do the trick:

```
$i = 0; Get-ChildItem x:\path\to\files | ForEach-Object {
    $i++
    $destPath = Join-Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath "$i $($_.Name)"
    Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $destPath
}
```

**Example:**

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                    
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                    
-a----         6/24/2021   7:08 PM              2 1 testfile0.txt
-a----         6/24/2021   7:08 PM              2 2 testfile1.txt
-a----         6/24/2021   7:08 PM              2 3 testfile2.txt
-a----         6/24/2021   7:08 PM              2 4 testfile3.txt
-a----         6/24/2021   7:08 PM              2 5 testfile4.txt
-a----         6/24/2021   7:08 PM              2 testfile0.txt  
-a----         6/24/2021   7:08 PM              2 testfile1.txt  
-a----         6/24/2021   7:08 PM              2 testfile2.txt  
-a----         6/24/2021   7:08 PM              2 testfile3.txt  
-a----         6/24/2021   7:08 PM              2 testfile4.txt
```