# PowerShell Rename Files in Folder For Loop Error

Tags: powershell, for-loop, rename

I'm trying to mass rename a bunch of 1000 *.json files in a folder but I'm having trouble actually executing the script.

Each file is incrementally named:
"Image 1.json",  "Image 2.json, ..... "Image 1000.json"

I want to rename them as integers (-1) without extensions (I know it sounds weird, but gotta do it).
So

1. "Image 1.json" becomes:   0
2. "Image 2.json" becomes:   1
3. "Image 423.json" becomes: 422
4. "Image 1000.json" becomes: 998

Just so I don't mess this up I create a test folder with only the first 10 files:

[image]

And I saved it:   `C:\test\testfolder`

Here's my script

```
$files = Get-Content
$x = 0
foreach ($file in $files) {
   Rename-Item $file $x
   $x++
}
```

I save the script in:   `C:\test\rename.ps1`

In PowerShell I navigate to the directory:

```
cd c:\test\testfolder\
```

Then in PowerShell I run the script

`C:\test\rename.ps1`

Power shell then gives me this ("Its asking me for input and I am entering numbers...it goes nowhere):

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: [1] try using the parameter names instead of just throwing values at the cmdlet and hoping they stick to the right parameter. [*grin*] ///// [2] have you tried just renaming the files with the non-digits removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$folder = 'X:\path\to\jsonfolder'
$i = 0
Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Filter *.json |
Sort-Object { [int][regex]::Match($_.BaseName,'\d+').Value } |
Rename-Item -NewName { [string]([ref]$i).Value++ }
```

---

`Sort-Object` is there because by the naming of your files, without it, you would jump from ***Image 1.json*** to ***Image 10.json*** and so on:

```
-a----          7/2/2021   7:32 PM              2 Image 1.json    
-a----          7/2/2021   7:32 PM              2 Image 10.json   
-a----          7/2/2021   7:32 PM              2 Image 100.json  
-a----          7/2/2021   7:32 PM              2 Image 1000.json 
-a----          7/2/2021   7:32 PM              2 Image 101.json  
-a----          7/2/2021   7:32 PM              2 Image 102.json
```

The `([ref]$i).Value++` trick comes from [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68122907/how-can-i-rename-files-by-prepending-a-sequence-number-to-the-original-file-name/68123347#68123347), credits to mklement0.

Answer (score 3):

`Get-Content` [reads content from a file or stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content), but you want to read the filenames in a directory. [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) is a way to do that; specify your path or use the current directory as shown below.

Don't forget to filter by extension, `*.json`.

I'm not sure if you really want sequential numbers or you want the number extracted from the filename. If the latter, you can try:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem *.json

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $newfile = $file -replace '(?<=\\)Image (\d+)\.json$', '$1'
    Rename-Item $file $newfile -WhatIf
}
```

Remove `-WhatIf` if you want to actually do the job.

Sample run:

```
    Directory: C:\Users\foo\Desktop\test


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----          7/2/2021     15:12              6 Image 1.json
-a----          7/2/2021     15:12              6 Image 2.json
-a----          7/2/2021     15:12              6 Image 3333.json
-a----          7/2/2021     15:46            250 rename.ps1


PS C:\Users\foo\Desktop\test> .\rename.ps1
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\foo\Desktop\test\Image 1.json Destination: C:\Users\foo\Desktop\test\1".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\foo\Desktop\test\Image 2.json Destination: C:\Users\foo\Desktop\test\2".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\foo\Desktop\test\Image 3333.json Destination: C:\Users\foo\Desktop\test\3333".
```