# global: not setting variables in functions in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, global

So I have a personal project I'm working on where I want to set the value of `$Name` to the name of the script without the path or file extensions. I thought I could do this as a global variable since it needs to called a few times.

I've used the `set-variable` command and used `$global:Name` but nothing seems to work when I call the variable in the function. I've also used other variable names such as "foo" and it still wasn't working. Here are some example code snippets:

```
Set-Variable -name Name -value [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($MyInvocation.ScriptName) -scope global
function test {
    $Name
}
test
Pause
```

I've also tried:

```
Set-Variable -name Name -value [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($MyInvocation.ScriptName) -scope global
function test {
    $global:Name
}
test
Pause
```

And:

```
$global:Name = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($MyInvocation.ScriptName)

function test {
    $Name
}
test
Pause
```

And:

```
$global:Name = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($MyInvocation.ScriptName)
function test {
    $global:Name
}
test
Pause
```

And:

```
$script:Name = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($MyInvocation.ScriptName)
function test {
    $script:Name
}
test
Pause
```

And:

```
$script:Name = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($MyInvocation.ScriptName)
function test {
    $Name
}
test
Pause
```

I was expecting the name of the script to appear but it just returns null. Anyone know why this is happening? Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: my understanding is that once you define a `$Global:` variable, you must **_always_** refer to it as such ... otherwise you will risk creating a new variable in the current scope.

Comment: Always using `$global:` is definitely the most robust way to refer to a global variable; specifically, it is _assigning_ to a variable of the same name without the `$global:` scope in a non-global scope that creates a _local_ variable that shadows the global one - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54317129/45375 for the full story.

Comment: @Excallypurr, zdan's answer solves your problem, but as an aside: using `Set-Variable` means that _argument-mode_ parsing is applied, so to use an _expression_ such as `[IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($MyInvocation.ScriptName)`  you need to enclose it in `(...)` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$MyInvocation` does not provide information about the current script. It tells you about who called the script. As per [the help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#myinvocation):

> Unlike the $PSScriptRoot and $PSCommandPath automatic variables, the
>   PSScriptRoot and PSCommandPath properties of the $MyInvocation
>   automatic variable contain information about the invoker or calling
>   script, not the current script.

So what you want to use is `$PSCommandPath`, like this:

```
$global:Name = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($PSCommandPath)
function test {
    $Name
}
test
```