# Why won't Variable update?

Tags: powershell, variables, scope

I'm currently editing our new employee script for AD and I am running into an issue, I added 2 radio buttons for the home folder, one radio button will update the BaseHomeFolderPath to Path1 and the second will update it to Path2, I export the variable to a csv to verify that it works but it keeps showing up blank. I don't know if it is a scope issue or what I am doing wrong, any help will be greatly appreciated! Below is a copy of the code.

I tried using $script: and it didn't work either.

```
$BaseHomeFolderPath = ''

Set-Variable -Name $BaseHomeFolderPath -Scope Global

$radiobuttonAtlas_MouseClick = [System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler]{
#Event Argument: $_ = [System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs]
    #TODO: Place custom script here
    $BaseHomeFolderPath = '\\path1\users'
}


$radiobuttonCerberus_MouseClick=[System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler]{
#Event Argument: $_ = [System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs]
    #TODO: Place custom script here
    $BaseHomeFolderPath = '\\path2\users'
}

$buttonRun_MouseClick=[System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler]{
#Event Argument: $_ = [System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs]
    #TODO: Place custom script here
    $TestValue = New-Object System.Object
    $TestValue | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Path" -Value $BaseHomeFolderPath
    $TestValue | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\Testcsv.csv"
}
```

I expect the BaseHomeFolderPath variable to be updated to whichever radio button is selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**

In order to update the `$BaseHomeFolderPath` variable in the *script* scope (or any scope other than the *local* one), you must reference it in that scope explicitly:

```
$script:BaseHomeFolderPath = '\\path1\users'
```

Otherwise, **without a scope specifier such as `$script:`, you'll implicitly create a *new* variable by that name in the *current* scope**, which in your case is the *child scope* in which your event handlers run.

---

In PowerShell, when you **assign to a variable with `$var = ...`**, you either:

- update a preexisting variable that was created *in the same scope*.
- or implicitly create a new variable *in the current scope*.

**The tricky part is that even though child scopes *see* variables created in parent scopes and can *get their value* by name only, *assigning to them by name only* creates a *new*, scope-local variable**, and that new variable then *shadows* the original one in the current scope and all child scopes.

A simple demonstration, using call operator `&` to execute a script block (`{ ... }`) in a child scope:

```
$var = 'parent'
"in parent: before: $var"
& {
  "in child: before: $var" # sees $var from parent scope 
  $var = 'child'           # creates new $var in current scope
  "in child: after: $var"  # sees new $var, which shadows the parent's
}
"in parent: after: $var"   # still has original value
```

This prints:

```
in parent: before: parent
in child: before: parent
in child: after: child
in parent: after: parent
```

Note:

- The behavior **also applies to** the *implicit* assignment that occurs with the **`++` and `--` operators** (given that, e.g., `++$var` is the same as `$var += 1`)

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72016352/45375) for an example of where this can constitute a pitfall.
- **In addition to *fixed*-target scope specifiers `$script:` and `$global:`, you can use the [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) / [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable) cmdlets with the `-Scope` parameter to target variables in scopes *relative* to the current one** (up the call stack; e.g., `-Scope 1` refers to the *parent* scope).
- To promote modularity and maintainability, **it's generally better to *avoid* accessing variables across scope boundaries** - best to pass *values* around instead.

For more information, see:

- [`Get-Help about_Scopes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes)
- The last section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347515/45375), which provides a concise summary.