# Avoid variable in module to be overriden by caller and vice-versa

Tags: powershell

I'm building a custom module in Powershell to factorize some code.

In the functions in the module, I use variables. However, if the caller use the same variable names, it can interfer with my module.

For example, here a small module (MyModule.psm1) :

```
function Get-Foo{
    param(
        [int]$x,
        [int]$y
    )

    try{
        $result = $x/$y

    } catch{
        Write-Warning "Something get wrong"
    }
    if($result -ne 0){
        Write-Host "x/y = $result"
    }
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function "Get-Foo"
```

And a sample script that use the module:

```
Import-Module "$PSScriptRoot\MyModule\MyModule.psm1" -Force

$result = 3 # some other computation

Get-Foo -x 42 -Y 0
```

The output is :

```
x/y = 3
```

As you can see, the caller declared a variable name that conflicts with the one in my module.

What is the best practice to avoid this behavior ?

As a requirement, I have to assume that the module's developer won't be the main script developer. Thus, the internal on the module is not supposed to be known (kinda black box)

Comment: Even though scoping does play a role here, one problem is that a terminating error was generated. As a result, `$result` is never set as intended. Your `if` statement in its current position never considers this possibility. If you move your `if` statement inside of your `try {}` block, your main symptom does not occur.

Comment: @AdminOfThings, I was assuming that if `$result` isn't set, it will contains the default value (0 for an integer, or null for a more real scenario)

Comment: @SteveB, referencing a non-existent variable in PowerShell by default evaluates to `$null` (if you have `Set-StrictMode -Version 1` or higher in effect, a statement-terminating error is triggered). Since `$null -ne 0` is `$true`, your `if` statement's block is entered.

Comment: I appreciate it, Steve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ivan Mirchev's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58319554/45375), [robdy's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58319745/45375) and [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings)'s comments on the question provide the crucial pointers; let me summarize and complement them:

- Inside your function, **a local `$result` variable is never created if parameter variable `$y` contains `0`**, because the division by zero causes a *statement-terminating error* (which triggers the `catch` block).
- **In the absence of a *local* `$result` variable, one defined in an *ancestral scope* may be visible** (parent scope, grandparent scope, ...), thanks to **PowerShell's *dynamic scoping***.

  - **In your case, `$result` was defined in the *global* scope**, which modules see as well, so your module function saw *that* value.

    - However, note that ***assigning* to `$result` implicitly creates a *local* variable by that name** rather than modifying the ancestral one. **Once created locally, the variable *shadows* the ancestral one by the same name**; that is, it hides it, unless you explicitly reference it in the scope in which it was defined.
  - Also note that modules by design do *not* see variables from a module-external caller *other* than the global scope, such as if your module is called from a *script*.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347515/45375) for more information about scopes in PowerShell.

---

**Solutions**:

- **Initialize local variable `$result` at the start of your function** to guarantee its existence - see below.
- Alternatively, refer to a local variable *explicitly* - I mention these options primarily for the sake of completeness and to illustrate fundamental concepts, I don't think they're practical:

  - You can use **scope specifier `$local:`**, which in the case of `$y` being `0` will cause `$local:result` to refer to a ***non-existent* variable** (unless you've initialized it before the failing division), which PowerShell **defaults to `$null`**:

    - `if ($null -ne $local:result) { Write-Host "x/y = $result" }`
    - **Caveat**: If [`Set-StrictMode`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/) `-Version 1` or higher is in effect, a reference to a non-existent variable causes a statement-terminating error (which means that the function / script as a whole will by default continue to execute at the next statement).
  - A strict-mode-independent, but verbose and slower alternative is to use the [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) cmdlet to explicitly test for the existence of your local variable:

    - `if (Get-Variable -ErrorAction Ignore -Scope Local result) { Write-Host "x/y = $result" }`

**Solution with initialization == creation of the local variable up front:**

```
function Get-Foo{
    param(
        [int]$x,
        [int]$y
    )

    # Initialize and thereby implicitly create
    # $result as a local variable.
    $result = 0

    try{
        $result = $x/$y
    } catch{
        Write-Warning "Something get wrong"
    }
    # If the division failed, $result still has its initial value, 0
    if($result -ne 0){
        Write-Host "x/y = $result"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is actually best practice, but my way to avoid this is to always declare the variables I use (unless I specifically need to use variable from parent scope, which sometimes happen). That way you make sure you never reach the value from parent scope in your module:

```bsh
# Declare
$result = $null
# Do something
$result = $x/$y
```

Of course in your example if seems like overkill, but in real life might be reasonable.

Another way I can think of is to change the scope.

```
$result => $private:result
```

Or to `$script:result` like [Mike suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58319595/9902555).

Comment: The "declaration" (initialization and thereby implicit creation) is a sensible approach. Instead of `$private:`, I assume you meant `$local:` to refer to a (potentially non-existent and therefore `$null`) local variable. Referring to the `$script:` scope technically works, but is conceptually confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that you are not assigning a value to the variable result, when dividing by zero, as it generates an error. 
You have a variable `$result` in the global scope (PowerShell console), which is being inherited into the function scope (Child scope and inheritance is parent to child, not vice versa)!
If you have a value, that is being assigned to the variable `$result` in the chatch block, for example, it could solve the issue. Something like:

```
function Get-Foo{
    param(
        [int]$x,
        [int]$y
    )

    try{
        $result = $x/$y

    } catch{
        Write-Warning "Something get wrong"
        $result = $_.exception.message 
    }
    if($result -ne 0){
        Write-Host "x/y = $result"
    }
}
```

Note: $_.exception.message = $error.Exception.message in this case

Another way would be to use the scope modifier for the variable result at the begining of the function: `$global:result = $null`. This way you will null the global variable (or provide other value), but then the result would be:

```
WARNING: Something get wrong
x/y =
```

Which is not really meaningful.

more details: `get-help about_Scopes -ShowWindow` or: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6

If you have more questions, I would be happy to address.

Comment: Good pointers, but I suggest not even mentioning the modification of the global variable (except to recommend against it).

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to have a good understanding of Powershell Scope Types.
There are four different types of scopes:
*Global Scope, 
Script Scope, 
Private Scope, 
Local Scope*

I think you need to make use of the script scope, because these scopes are created when you run/execute a PS1 script/module. This means that you have to define the variable like:

```
$script:x
$script:y
```

Comment: using `$script:` prefix works perfectly. However, that make the module code a bit less readable and a bit more complex to write.

Comment: I agree. I don't like it either but we have to work with scopes in this situations. Maybe someone has a good alternative to avoid using a scopetype before every variable? Great i could help you with this :-)

Comment: Bringing the _script_ scope into the mix is unnecessary and conceptually confusing (aside from the fact that the problem relates to `$result`, not `$x` and `$y`); you can use `$local:` to refer to a local variable explicitly (`$local:result`) which if non-existent by default evaluates to `$null`) or, better yet, explicitly and initialize and thereby create the local variable of interest at the start of your function: `$result = 0`.