# Modifying variable in parent script using child script in powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, scope

I have two powershell scripts.
I have to assign the parent variable using child script
The child powershell script is called using parent powershell script

parent.ps1

```
$count = $Null
```

child.ps1

```
$count = 10
```

How do I make sure that the change in child script gets reflected in parent script?

Comment: `$global:count = 10`. See [About Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes)

Comment: How are you starting the child.ps script? If you do not need it to run in its own script scope, you can dot source it. That way you can avoid global variables.

Comment: @ManuelBatsching Yes I am calling child script in parent script...is it possible to update the variable in parent script using child script?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Manuel Batsching's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60437851/45375) shows you how to use *dot-sourcing* to solve your problem *indirectly*: by executing the child script *directly in the parent script's scope*, *all* of the child script's (script-level) variables (among other definitions, namely functions and aliases) are created directly in the parent script's scope, which may be undesirable.

**PowerShell *does* offer mechanisms to selectively modify variables in other [scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes), but it's best to avoid them**, because you're creating a tight coupling between your scripts that makes them difficult to maintain; instead, use other mechanism to communicate information between your scripts, in the simplest form via *output*.

If you still want to solve your problem by modifying a variable in the parent scope, you can use the following:

```
# When run in child.ps1 that was invoked (normally) by parent.ps1,
# sets $count to 1 in the scope of *parent.ps1*.
Set-Variable -Scope 1 -Name count -Value 10
```

`Scope -1` refers to the *parent* scope of the calling scope (`2` would refer to the *grandparent* scope, and so on) - see [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable).

Complementarily, **scope modifiers `$script:` and `$global:`** may be used with variable names to target variables in the (same) *script* scope and the *global* scope (for instance, `$script:foo = 'bar'` could be used to set a script-level variable from inside of a *function* defined in the same script; creating or modifying *global* variables should be avoided, as they linger even after a script exits) - see [`about_Scopes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes).

For the sake of completeness:

- Scope modifier **`$local:`** allows you to refer to the *current* (local) scope explicitly; it is rarely used, because **the current scope is *implied* when you *assign* to a variable by mere name** (e.g., `$foo = 'bar'` creates a local `$foo` variable).

  - However, on *getting* a variable `$local:foo` isn't necessarily the same as just `$foo`: due to PowerShell's *dynamic* scoping, `$foo` returns the *value of* a variable in an *ancestral scope*, if any, if no such variable exists in the *current* scope; by contrast, `$local:foo` strictly returns the value of a variable by that name in the *current* scope, if defined there.
  - To *suppress* dynamic scoping for a given variable, i.e. to prevent descendant scopes from seeing it (by default), create it with the **`$private:`** scope modifier.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347515/45375) for more information about PowerShell's dynamic scoping and the `$private:` scope.
- Scope modifier **`$using:`** is used in the context of *remoting* and *jobs*; it doesn't actually reference a *variable per se* in the caller's context, but its *value* - see [`about_Remote_Variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote_Variables#using-local-variables).

Answer (score 1):

By using the dot sourcing operator `.` you can run your child.ps1 script in the same scope as your parent.ps1 script. That will preserve all changes to variables, that your child script does (see: [script scope and dot sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing)).

Let the content of your parent.ps1 be like:

```
$count = $null
. .\child.ps1
$count
```

This will return `10`.

Comment: It's worth noting that this solves the problem _indirectly_, with a major side effect: _all_ of the child script's (script-level) variables are created directly in the parent script's scope, which may be undesirable.