# Get-Variable defined in a scriptblock from a psm function

Tags: powershell, module, scope

I have the following piece of code:

```
$x = 'xyz'
& {
    $y = 'abc'
    foo
}
```

The `foo` function is defined in the `foo.psm1` module which is imported before the script block is started.

Inside the `foo` function, I call `Get-Variable` which shows me `x` but it doesn't show `y`. I tried playing with the `-Scope` parameter: `Local`, `Script`, `Global`, `0` - which is the local scope from what I understood from the docs, `1` - which is the parent scope.

How could I get the `y` variable inside the `foo` function?

I'm not looking for a solution such as passing it as an argument. I want something as `Get-Variable` but sadly it doesn't see it for some reason.

***UP***

Based on the comments received, probably more context is needed.

Say that foo receives a `ScriptBlock` which is using the `$using:` syntax.

```
$x = 'xyz'
& {
    $y = 'abc'
    foo -ScriptBlock {
        Write-Host $using:x
        Write-Host $using:y
    }
}
```

I'm 'mining' these variables as follows:

```
$usingAsts = $ScriptBlock.Ast.FindAll( { param($ast) $ast -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.UsingExpressionAst] }, $true) | ForEach-Object { $_ -as [System.Management.Automation.Language.UsingExpressionAst] }
foreach ($usingAst in $usingAsts) {
    $varAst = $usingAst.SubExpression -as [System.Management.Automation.Language.VariableExpressionAst]
    $var = Get-Variable -Name $varAst.VariablePath.UserPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

This is how I'm using `Get-Variable` and in the case presented above, `y` cannot be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules run in their own *scope domain* (aka *session state*), which means they generally do *not* see the caller's variables - unless (a module-external) caller runs directly in the *global* scope.

- For an overview of scopes in PowerShell, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347515/45375).

However, assuming that you define the function in your module as  an [advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) one, there *is* a way to access the caller's state, namely via the [automatic `$PSCmdlet` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pscmdlet).

Here's a simplified example, using a *dynamic* module created via the [`New-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-module) cmdlet:

```sh
# Create a dynamic module that defines function 'foo'
$null = New-Module {
  function foo {    
    # Make the function and advanced (cmdlet-like) one, via
    # [CmdletBinding()].
    [CmdletBinding()] param()
    # Access the value of variable $bar in the
    # (module-external) caller's scope.
    # To get the variable *object*, use:
    #    $PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.Get('bar')
    $PSCmdlet.GetVariableValue('bar')
  }
}

& {
  $bar = 'abc'
  foo
}
```

The above outputs verbatim `abc`, as desired.