# Running IF Statements in a Function in Powershell

Tags: function, powershell, if-statement

I'm a total Powershell newbie and I'm having difficulty with a script I'm trying to come up with.

The script creates a form to map network drives, and as some of those drives are on a different domain it gives the user the option to enter a username themselves `$txtUsername.Text` or use the currently logged in user name `$LoggedInUser`.

When the user clicks the OK button on the form, the function `btnOK_Click` is called and I want it to essentially to run this statement: `If ($txtUsername.Text -eq "") {$User = $LoggedInUser } Else {$User = $txtUsername.Text}`

If I run that statement manually, it works as expected - `$User` is set to the value the user enters, or if they don't enter a value it uses the currently logged in username. But I can't figure out how to make it work within a function. If I try it like this:

```
function btnOK_Click {If ($txtUsername.Text -eq "") {$User = $LoggedInUser } Else {$User = $txtUsername.Text}}
```

Nothing happens - `$User` isn't defined - though there are no errors.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? If it helps I can post the whole code I have, but as it's 250+ lines, I thought it best to just post the part I'm having trouble with.

Comment: You're defining and assigning `$user` inside a function, the variable will __only live inside that scope__.

Comment: For an overview of how scopes work in PowerShell, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347515/45375).

Comment: Ah, that's very helpful - thank you both. I'll read through that answer tomorrow (it's 10pm here in the UK - time for a few cold ones!) But I've skimmed through it, and it does indeed seem to answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your $user variable global & therefore accessible outside of your function

replace $user with $Global:user