# access parent scriptblock scope in powershell

Tags: powershell, scope, scriptblock

As part of learning its basics i am implementing a ternary operator cmdlet in pws.
I have it taking scriptblocks, to emulate the conditional evaluation ternary operators usually have.
And in most instances it works fine.

```
function valOf($var){
    if($var -is [scriptblock]){
        return & $var   }
    else {
        return $var    }
}

function ternary([bool]$condition, $t, $f){
    if($condition){
        return valOf($t)    }
    else{
        return valOf($f)    }
    #return @($t,$f)[!$condition]
}
```

I got in trouble when i started nesting scriptblocks:

```
$i=56;
&{
   $i=0
   ternary($true) {$script:i+=2} {write-host "onFalse"}
   $i #wanted:2 #reality: 58
   <# without '$script: $i' is indeed 0, but cannot be edited #>
}      
$i #wanted:56 #reality:58
```

**How can i access the middle scope?**

browsing the documentation as well as the forum this seems to be quite a common issue, but the theme is anything but clear x.x
Perhaps an invokeCommand that optsOut from the copyOnWrite behaviour..?

Comment: the inner `$i` would be `Get-Variable i -Scope 0` the outer would be `Get-Variable i -Scope 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to [Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76772233/45375) that makes it unnecessary to use special syntax in the script-block arguments passed to your ternary function:

You can combine [dynamic modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-module) with [dot-sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-):

Note: For brevity:

- The `ternary` function below doesn't handle the case where the arguments aren't script blocks, but that's easy to add.
- The `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute is omitted; you don't strictly need an *advanced* function to make the solution work, though it's certainly advisable, and adding something like `[Parameter(Mandatory)]` would *implicitly* make your function an advanced one.

```bash
# Create (and implicitly import) a dynamic module that
# hosts the ternary function.
$null = New-Module {
  # Define the ternary function.
  function ternary {
    param(
      [bool] $Condition,
      [scriptblock] $trueBlock,
      [scriptblock] $falseBlock
    )
    # Dot-source the appropriate script block,
    # which runs directly in the *caller's* scope,
    # given that's where it was created and given that the
    # module's code runs in a separate scope domain ("session state")
    if ($Condition) { . $trueBlock } else { . $falseBlock }
  }
}

$i=56;
& {
   $i=0
   # Now you can use $i as-is
   # in order to refer to the current scope's $i.
   ternary $true { $i+=2 } {write-host "onFalse"}
   $i # -> 2 
}
$i # -> 56
```

Note:

- While a *dynamic* module is used above, the technique equally works with *persisted* modules (`*.psm1`)
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347515/45375) provides a comprehensive overview of scopes in PowerShell, including the separate scope domains (trees) for *modules*, somewhat unfortunately called *session states* in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes#modules)

Comment: This looks just like what i was looking for ^^  
would it work with a normal .psm1 module as well?

Comment: @AndreaBardelli, yes, it should; please see my update, which also provides links to more information about (module) scopes in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `ternary` function is an [advanced function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.3), for instance (notice the `[cmdletbinding()]` decoration):

```bash
function ternary {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [bool] $condition,
        [scriptblock] $ifTrue,
        [scriptblock] $ifFalse
    )

    if ($condition) {
        return & $ifTrue
    }

    & $ifFalse
}
```

Then you can leverage [`$PSCmdlet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscmdlet?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0) to get and update the value `$i` in the inner scope:

```
$i = 56

& {
    $i = 0
    ternary $true { $PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.Get('i').Value += 2 } { Write-Host 'onFalse' }
    $i # 2
}

$i # 56
```

If the `ternary` **is not advanced**, the you can use [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable?view=powershell-7.3) targeting scope `2` for the function in this answer:

```
ternary $true { (Get-Variable i -Scope 2).Value += 2 } { Write-Host 'onFalse' }
```

For the function in your question you would need to use scope `3` because the scriptblock is passed to and executed by `valOf` adding `+1` to the scope.

Personally, I would change your function to:

```
function ternary([bool] $condition, $t, $f) {
    if ($condition) {
        if ($t -is [scriptblock]) {
            return & $t
        }

        return $t
    }

    if ($f -is [scriptblock]) {
        return & $f
    }

    $f
}
```

Then you can use `-Scope 2` without issues.

In both cases, advanced or non-advanced, using [`$ExecutionContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.executioncontext?view=net-7.0) should also work:

```
ternary $true { $ExecutionContext.SessionState.PSVariable.Get('i').Value += 2 } { Write-Host 'onFalse' }
```

Comment: I tried with -scope 0, 1 and 2 and they all give me the error "cannot find a variable with name 'i'"

Comment: @AndreaBardelli hehe, with your function, then the scope is `3`, because `ternary` is passing the object to `valOf` which then executes the scriptblock adding +1 to the scope. What you should do instead is check if `$f` and `$t` are scriptblock in `ternary` itself, or at least, execute them in it

Comment: @AndreaBardelli I updated to clarify this. Hopefully it makes sense why for your function scope `3` is needed

Comment: Firstly ty for the answer.   
The top would be not having to use lengthy syntax, as the main purpose of a ternary operator is being concise. But for all other purposes it's fine